# Tilting Laser Problem : PR2 blocked by a virtual obstacle wall

Tags: laser

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I run the pr2_2dnav_slam, the tilting laser seems to have some problem. Therefore the robot will think that it is stuck in the obstacles and won't move.

[image: fig1]

Then I try to show the tilting laser alone.

[image: fig2]

It looks like that there are some problem with the transform from the tilting laser to the base_link.

Beside, the laser seems to be wrapped up in a circle, which is very similar to the condition in fig1.

Is there any wrong with the setting of the tilting laser, or what might the problem be?

Thanks for any advise.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/84241/tilting-laser-problem-:-pr2-blocked-by-a-virtual-obstacle-wall/) by [Albert K](https://answers.ros.org/users/1569/albert-k/) on ROS Answers with karma: 301 on 2013-09-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've seen this sort of errors when there's a timing offset between computers on the PR2. The tilting laser is very sensitive to timing offsets since it moves quickly.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-09-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Albert K](https://answers.ros.org/users/1569/albert-k/) on 2013-09-29**:
I checked the dashboard and found that there are warnings like "NTP offset from c1 to c2 ; Offset too great." Therefore I followed this: pr2support.willowgarage.com/wiki/PR2 Manual/Chapter13#Clock_Synchronization, and sync the clock. After that the problem disappeared!! Thank you very much~

**Comment by [Albert K](https://answers.ros.org/users/1569/albert-k/) on 2013-09-29**:
I wonder why the tilting laser is sensitive to the timing offset? How does the timing offset interact with the system that finally result in such phenomenon.